# TypeError: Error #1009 cant find the NULL object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got this really annoying error 
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at monke2_fla::MainTimeline/update2()"
I can't find the NULL var, any help would be great as the script works fine, apart from the #1009 error.

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 800;

Banana_mc1.x = randomX;
Banana_mc1.y = 0;

var speed:Number = 10;
var speed2:Number = 5;
var speed3:Number = 2;
var speed4:Number = 6;
Banana_mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);
var playerScore:int = 0;
var stopLoop = 0;
if (stopLoop == 1) { } else {
function moveDown(e:Event):void
{
 Banana_mc1.y += speed; 
 Banana_mc2.y += speed2;
     Banana_mc3.y += speed3;
         Banana_mc4.y += speed3;
         Banana_mc5.y += speed;
         Banana_mc6.y += speed4;
     Snake_mc1.y += speed2;
          Bunch.y += speed3;
      Snake_mc2.y += speed3;
}
}
// KEYS
stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myFunction) ;
//Monkey.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function myFunction (event: KeyboardEvent)
{
  if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)  
    Monkey.x -= 10;

  if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) 
    Monkey.x += 10;
}
var hitAry:Array = [Banana_mc1,Banana_mc2,Banana_mc3,Banana_mc4,Banana_mc5,Banana_mc6];
var hitAry2:Array = [Snake_mc1,Snake_mc2];
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update2);
function update2(e:Event):void
{
var hitAry:Array = [Banana_mc1,Banana_mc2,Banana_mc3,Banana_mc4,Banana_mc5,Banana_mc6];
var hitAry2:Array = [Snake_mc1,Snake_mc2];
    for (var i:int=0; i < hitAry.length; i++) {
        if (Monkey.hitTestObject(hitAry[i])) {

            trace("HIT");
            hitAry[i].parent.removeChild(hitAry[i]);
            trace(hitAry[i]);
            playerScore+=1;
               playerScoreText.text = ("" + playerScore);
        } else { 

            trace("MISS"); }
               if (Floor.hitTestObject(hitAry[i])) {

            trace("HIT The Floor");
            hitAry[i].gotoAndPlay(35);
                   stopLoop = 1;

        } else { 

            trace("MISS"); }
} 

    for (var b:int=0; b < hitAry2.length; b++) {
        if (Monkey.hitTestObject(hitAry2[b])) {
   Monkey.Head.gotoAndPlay(23);
            trace("HIT");
            hitAry2[b].parent.removeChild(hitAry2[b]);
            playerScore-=1;
            if (playerScore <= 0) { playerScore = 0; }

               playerScoreText.text = ("" + playerScore);
        } else { 

            trace("MISS"); }

} 
  if (Monkey.hitTestObject(allleft)) {
    Monkey.Head.gotoAndPlay(23);
            trace("BITE");
                        playerScore-=100;
            if (playerScore <= 0) { playerScore = 0; }

               playerScoreText.text = ("" + playerScore);
        } else { 

            trace("NO BITE"); }
              if (Monkey.hitTestObject(allright)) {
    Monkey.Head.gotoAndPlay(23);
            trace("BITE");
                        playerScore-=100;
            if (playerScore <= 0) { playerScore = 0; }

               playerScoreText.text = ("" + playerScore);
        } else { 

            trace("NO BITE"); }
if (Monkey.hitTestObject(Bunch)) {

            trace("HIT BUNCH");
            Bunch.parent.removeChild(Bunch);
            playerScore+=10;
               playerScoreText.text = ("" + playerScore);
        } 


}
```

This is for an assignment that is over due and I am hitting a brick wall, Thanks in advance

- Chelsea

Comment: This is not going to be enough to go off of. Unfortunately, that is the pitfall of coding in the timeline. It could be that any number of your movieclips/display objects or children are not setup correctly. Make sure your instance names are correct. Review your parent/child hierarchy, make sure things like "Bunch.parent" actually has a parent object. Add in trace statements to determine the last thing that runs before the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, near the bottom of your code you say: `Bunch.parent.removeChild(Bunch);`

But you also have: `Banana_mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);` which invokes a function that keeps referring to **Bunch**.

You could test that by NOT removing **Bunch**. If that fixes the null var problem then you'll have to decide how to proceed. Do you want the game to continue or end after **Bunch** goes away?

Then there's also this:

```
    hitAry[i].parent.removeChild(hitAry[i]);
    trace(hitAry[i]);
```

You're trying to trace it right after you remove it! *That* mightmake hitAry[i] null!

Comment: This won't nullify the `hitAry[i]` as is, but if a certain element in `hitAry` is not added to stage (or was just removed from its parent), its `parent` property is null. Most likely this is the error OP has, although hitting `Bunch` might produce the same.